# access Meteor.users from template.onRendered

Tags: meteor

I need to execute this piece of code

```
Template.addPost.onRendered ->
@$('#name').val(Meteor.user().profile.name)
```

But it seems that the template is rendered earlier than `Users collection` gets populated on the Client. Thus returning me

```
Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined
```

How do I tackle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wait for the user to be loaded via an [autorun](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_autorun):

```coffee
Template.addPost.onRendered ->
  @autorun (c) ->
    # extract the name in a safe way
    {name} = Meteor.user()?.profile

    # once a name has been found, update the DOM and stop the autorun
    if name
      # note that name is an id so we don't need @$
      $('#name').val name
      c.stop()
```

We are also taking advantage of coffeescript's existential operator to safely extract the name value. In javascript this solution would look something like this:

```js
Template.addPost.onRendered(function() {
  this.autorun(function(c) {
    var user = Meteor.user()
    var name = user && user.profile && user.profile.name;
    if (name) {
      $('#name').val(name);
      c.stop();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much) Can you elaborate on two things: 1.What is this curly notation of curly braces - ```{name}```?; 2.Why don't I need @$ for jquery? the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_findAll) say I need to reference the template..

Comment: Have a look at "Destructuring Assignment" in the [docs](http://coffeescript.org/). `{x} = y` is shorthand for `x = y.x`. You don't need to search within the template because `#name` can only exist once on the page (it's an id), so searching within the whole page will yield the same result.

Comment: But isn't traversing the template is faster than traversing the whole page? I guess it's irrelevant in my case, but in theory...

Comment: Whoa! You're _the_ David Weldon from https://dweldon.silvrback.com/! Kudos for all those fine articles, mate!

Comment: I'm not sure about the performance difference, but it won't matter unless you have an absurd number of DOM elements. Yes that's me - I'm glad you like the blog. :D