# How to wait for Meteor.user() to be defined in Template onRendered

Tags: javascript, google-maps, meteor, coffeescript

I am working on a Meteor project and I need to access some information stored in a user's profile to make a map on the page. However, when I try to access Meteor.user(), I receive undefined because when the function is called, Meteor.user() has not been loaded.

```
Template.body.onRendered () ->
    console.log Meteor.user()
    address = Meteor.user()['profile']['address']

    GoogleMaps.ready 'studyMap', (map) ->
        # maps code that relies on address
```

Because Meteor.user() is not defined, I am not able to get the map to work. How can I wait for Meteor.user() to be defined?

Answer (score 0):

I think your going to need an asynchronous callback to load the map only when `address = Meteor.user()['profile']['address']` loads. As far as how to implement this, I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 0):

One of my apps has to do something similar to wait on a subscription. I defined the waitOn() handler in my router.

```
Router.map(function(){
  this.route('Brocator', {
    path: '/',
    template: 'brocator',
    waitOn: function() {
      return (Meteor.subscribe('people', this.params._gridId)
        && Meteor.subscribe('gridlog', this.params._gridId) );
    },
    data: function() {
      var gridId = this.params._gridId;
      return (People.find({gridId: gridId})
        && GridLog.find({gridId: gridId}));
    },
    fastRender: true
  }),
  ... other routes deleted for clarity
})
```

You may decide to use something along the lines of

```
return Meteor.user() != 'undefined';
```

in your waitOn() handler.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried to add the waitOn to my router, but I'm running into a few problems. First, the waitOn throws an error, saying "fn is not a function" (my function is simply () -> return Meteor.user() != undefined), so the waitOn isn't working. Secondly, the console.log from the actual client is logged before the waitOn is called, so it's happening even earlier. Any thoughts?

Comment: Looks like the rendered handler that I use got deprecated and the behavior is changed subtly with the new onRender. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809702/meteor-js-templates-rendered-vs-onrendered I'll have to look at how to update this for my code as well.

Comment: This has almost the exact code you're looking for. It will " wait for the user to be loaded via an autorun". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222429/access-meteor-users-from-template-onrendered

Answer (score 0):

Posted an answer for meteor/react [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39560279/meteor-react-how-to-wait-for-meteor-user/46557533#46557533) however the same can be done with blaze. I am not familiar with blaze but within your `Template.body.onRendered` function you can listen to make sure that the login services are configured before rendering anything.

```
Tracker.autorun(() => {
  if (Accounts.loginServicesConfigured()) {
    // accounts is ready go ahead and render
  } else {
    // still waiting show loading spinner
  }
});
```

I would recommend extracting this logic out to a higher level so that you don't keep repeating the same code.