# Meteor/React - How to wait for Meteor.user()

Tags: meteor, meteor-react

I'm struggling to figure out how to wait for the `Meteor.user()` subscription in a react component. I know the user is logged in because `Meteor.userId()` returns the `_id`, but trying to access the email address show `Meteor.user()` returns undefined. I assume because it's not available just yet.

Alas, since Meteor.user() isn't a publication I manually subscribe to, I'm not sure how to wait for it in a React component. Can someone point me towards an example?

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

import './BaseLayout.scss';


class BaseLayout extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isAuthenticated: (Meteor.userId() !== null) ? true : false,
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        if (!this.state.isAuthenticated) {
            this.context.router.push('/login');
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (!this.state.isAuthenticated) {
            this.context.router.push('/login');
        }
    }

    toggleUserMenu() {
        this.refs.userMenu.style.display = (this.refs.userMenu.style.display === 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
    }

    logout(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Meteor.logout();
        this.context.router.push('/login');
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div id="base">
                <div id="header">
                    <div id="top-bar" className="clear-fix">
                        <div className="float-left" id="logo"></div>
                        <div className="float-right" id="user-menu">
                            <div onClick={this.toggleUserMenu.bind(this)}>
                                <span>{this.props.currentUser.emails[0].address}</span>
                                <div className="arrow-down"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="user-menu-content" ref="userMenu">
                                <a onClick={this.logout.bind(this)}>Sign Out</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="bodyContainer">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
                <div id="footer">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="mailto:test@example.com">Made by Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
BaseLayout.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}


export default BaseLayoutContainer = createContainer(() => {

    var handle = Meteor.subscribe("user.classrooms");

    return {
        currentUser: Meteor.user(),
        dataLoading: !handle.ready(),
        classrooms: Classrooms.find({}).fetch(),
    };
}, BaseLayout);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a ternary operation

```
currentUser ? true : flase
```

Also a great tip to keep components organized is to always `destructure` for example instead of doing `const currentUser = this.props.currentUser` you can do `const { currentUser } = this.props;` Have a look:

```
render() {
const { currentUser, children } = this.props;
  return (
  <div id="base">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="top-bar" className="clear-fix">
        <div className="float-left" id="logo"></div>
        <div className="float-right" id="user-menu">
          <div onClick={this.toggleUserMenu.bind(this)}>
           {currentUser ?
             <span>{currentUser.emails[0].address}</span> :
             <span>Loading...</span>
           }
            <div className="arrow-down"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="user-menu-content" ref="userMenu">
            <a onClick={this.logout.bind(this)}>Sign Out</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bodyContainer">
      {children}
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="mailto:test@example.com">Made by Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
)
}
```

Comment: I love it when the answer is obvious, just wish I would've seen it! Thank you so much for the tip about destructuring, I can see how it will keep the markup cleaner and less dependent. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help @DMX Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is good however after awhile you will notice that you will have to repeat this many times on many components. Alternatively you can listen to make sure that the `Accounts.loginServicesConfigured()` is true before even rendering at the top level component with `Tracker`. Quoting the meteor docs: "The function Accounts.loginServicesConfigured() is a reactive data source that will return true once the login service is configured". I am using meteor, react, redux, and react router.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Tracker } from 'meteor/tracker';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { loading: true };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    Tracker.autorun(() => {
      if (Accounts.loginServicesConfigured()) {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        {
          this.state.loading ? (<Spinner />) : (
            <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
          )
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Hopefully this alternative helps someone else out. Good luck!

Comment: this answer is ideal if you're using redirects with react router but want to avoid loading the router when the user data hasn't loaded yet, thanks a ton!

Comment: awesome glad i can help!

Answer (score 2):

Add dataLoading: !handle.ready() || !Meteor.user() to the createContainer.

```
export default BaseLayoutContainer = createContainer(() => {

  var handle = Meteor.subscribe("user.classrooms");

  return {
    currentUser: Meteor.user(),
    dataLoading: !handle.ready() || !Meteor.user(),
    classrooms: Classrooms.find({}).fetch(),
  };
}, BaseLayout);
```

`Meteor.user()` will be undefined inside the component before loading so make sure you prevent it's calling by adding a condition such as `dataLoading ? "" : Meteor.user()`.

You can also check if user is logged in with `!!Meteor.user()`. Normally `Meteor.userId()` is faster to load but if you need to access user's data such as email you need to call `Meteor.user()` in that case no need to call both.

Answer (score 1):

Here are mine 2 cents

Beware if you're using Meteor.user in can be undefined during server restart or some other cases so you need to check it it's either object or null
[check meteor docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-user)

So if I take Rimskys's answer it should look like this.

```
export default BaseLayoutContainer = createContainer(() => {

  var handle = Meteor.subscribe("user.classrooms");
  var user = Meteor.user()
  return {
    currentUser: Meteor.user(),
    dataLoading: !handle.ready() || !(Accounts.loginServicesConfigured() && (user || user === null)),
    classrooms: Classrooms.find({}).fetch(),
  };
}, BaseLayout);
```

Also, I think it's probably a good idea to redirect the user to login or forbidden page if user is null.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, hope it helps you.

```
const Loading = () => <div>LOADING</div>;

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, user, ...props }) =>
  <Route
    {...props}
    render={props => {
      if (user) return <Component {...props} />;
      if (user === null)
        return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location }}} />

      return <Loading />
    }}
  />;

const AdminRoute = ({ component: Component, user, ...props }) => {
  const userData = user || {};
  const admin = userData.admin || false;

  return <Route
    {...props}
    render={props => {
      if (user && admin) return <Component {...props} />;
      if (user && !admin) return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location }}} />;
      return <Loading />
    }}
  />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for an option that uses hooks, but found this. If anyone will need to solve this with hooks.

Inspired by the responses above I added "meteor/react-meteor-data" to the equation and it looks super sleek:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

export const App = () => {
  const accountsReady = useTracker(() => Accounts.loginServicesConfigured(), []); //make sure the account system loaded

  //TODO: Design a loader
  if(!accountsReady){
    return (<h2>Loading...</h2>)
  }

  //Once the loginService has loaded - do whatever
  return (<YourApp/>)

}
```